# three.js calculate surfaces of stl files

Tags: import, three.js, 3d

I think i have a difficult problem right here..
I want to able to get the surfaces of f.e. the orange object in this three.js example https://threejs.org/examples/?q=stl#webgl_loader_stl

i want to click with the mouse, find the correct surface, which should then be highlighted, so i make sure this was the surface i want.
(i already implemented raycaster successfully, so thats not an issue)

Answer (score 1):

The `intersectObject` method returns an array of intersections, each of which has `face` property.  The face contains vertex indices.

For STL files containing multiple solids, each solid is assigned to a different group, and the groups are available in the geometry object that is returned from `STLLoader`. Each group is defined by a range of vertex indices.

So, I think you can correlate the vertex indices returned from the raycaster with the vertex indices in the geometry groups.